# spree order confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, email-templates

I need to modify the emails which go to the customers in the spree app.

At the moment a very ordinary form goes to the customer email.

I am unable to find the code where I can modify that email and add custom template.

Anyone having worked on this point earlier?

Answer (score 0):

The mail templates are in `core/app/mailers/spree` and the mail that goes out after orders should be `core/app/mailers/spree/order_mailer.rb`.

Comment: all I have under my mailers is `application_mailer.rb` and `user_mailer.rb`

Comment: what version are you using ? I just checked out their git repository.

Comment: I am using `gem 'spree', '3.0.5'` which is Feb release.

Answer (score 0):

In `app/mailers/spree` you need to create a file called `order_mailer_decorator.rb`. In this file you add:

```
Spree::OrderMailer.class_eval do
    def confirm_email(order, resend = false)
        your code 
    end
end
```

In `views/spree/order_mailer` in a file `confirm_email.html.erb` you need to write your code.